# How should my INSERT INTO be formatted to avoid syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep receiving syntax error but I don't know where I am going wrong. Here is the table code:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
  `username` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userid_UNIQUE` (`userid`)
)
```

That goes through correctly. I then try to enter data and I receive the error after this:

```
   INSERT INTO users (name, username, address, city, state, zip, password)
    INSERT INTO users VALUES ('Bonnie Buntcake', 'bbunt', '6709 Wonder Street', 'Wonderbread', 'OH', '46105', 'eclectic');
```

It says at line 2, but I don't understand what is wrong with line 2. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Here's the relevant MySQL documentation if you ever need a handy reference ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: Note that this line is redundant: `UNIQUE KEY userid_UNIQUE (userid)` - a PRIMARY KEY is, by definition, UNIQUE.

Comment: And a zip might be numbers, but it isn't really an integer.

Answer (score 3):

List the columns, but in the same `insert` that has the `values`:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, username, address, city, state, zip, password)
    VALUES ('Bonnie Buntcake', 'bbunt', '6709 Wonder Street', 'Wonderbread', 'OH', '46105', 'eclectic');
```

It

Comment: That did the trick thank you so much. My info sheet provided to me was incorrect. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

In insert query specified the column name in first braces that you want to insert, specifying column name is considered as a good practice of query development.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `username`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `password`)
    VALUES ('Bonnie Buntcake', 'bbunt', '6709 Wonder Street', 'Wonderbread', 'OH', '46105', 'eclectic');
```